# Ruby on Rails: Mock session variable in helper class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, rspec, mocking

I am trying to mock the session hash in a controller's helper file:

**Helper_Spec:**

```
session.stub!(:[]).with("fb_token")
  RotaHelper.getListOfFriends.should == expected_friends
```

**Helper:**

```
FbGraph::User.me(session["fb_token"]).friends
```

**Error:**

```
NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `session' for RotaHelper:Module
```

Am I stubbing it incorrectly? Or helpers do not have acces to the session hash?

Comment: I don't have many experience on helper, and I don't think it's a good idea to access session from helper. as far as I see, helper is used for "views" only.

Comment: I think I found out what the problem is: I dont think you can access the session variable from helpers - I guess its because it does not inherits ApplicationController. I might be wrong tho ... any opinions?

Answer (score 2):

That's strange. In my helper tests, a session hash is created automatically. Maybe you didn't require spec_helper?

By the way, if the session wasn't created automatically by spec helper, you could also initialize it by saying that is a method of the helper. Like the following code:

```
session_hash = {}
helper.stub!(:session) { session_hash }
```